# Why there is no countOf method in the String Class?

Tags: java, string

We have utility methods like indexOf and other ..Of() mehtods in String class of Java. But the countOf method would be nice to have. Is this method left intentionally?
(and if so, that bring to the real question why?) 
or it did not occour to them?

Comment: `countOf()` what ? what is it supposed to count ?

Comment: like the occurrance of any char like "a" of a given string. Something like: if str is string object then str.countOf("a");

Comment: Let aside some introductory programming exercises, when would you need it?

Comment: I am not saying that if java did not provide indexOf() method in string then we can not calulcate the index of the given char in a string. And it is up to imagination on when we would need the countOf() method, there are number of cases and requirements. Again i was interseted in discussion of is there any particular reason behind leaving it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for including it? Other than it's convenient for you?

Comment: Yes, the first few things that comes to my mind is the performance optimization, handling complex string matching patterns,And standard JDK provided behaviour. And yes these methods are primarily for convenience.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to ask the JDK developers **why** they didn't implement such a method, although it's pretty easy to jimmy up such a utility yourself:

```
public static int countOf (String s, char c) {
    return s.length() - s.replace(c, "").length();
}
```

Or, if you're willing to use third parties, there are a few standard implementations, such as Apache commons-lang `StringUtils.countMatches`.

Comment: why my comment was removed? I had not written any objectionable comment, I just pointed out a change in code, That the replace method doesn't have (char, String) parameters.